# How to transform Beta distribution of second kind into Beta distribution of first kind?

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, continuous-data, beta-distribution

[image]!

I tried to solve it in a way but I can't complete in as I don't get any idea how to integrate the Beta kind two integrand within a finite boundary.

Comment: Simply use change of variables. $y=\frac{1}{1+x}\implies x=\frac{1-y}{y}$ and $x>0\implies 0<y<1$. So, $f_Y(y)=f_X(\frac{1-y}{y})\left|\frac{dx}{dy}\right|=\cdots$

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag.